# How to remove all directories in a folder in command line?

Tags: linux, command, rm

I want to remove all directories in a folder, no mater the specified directory is empty or not.
Can I do this in command line?

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to remove all subdirectories in a folder without deleting the files.

Then the following bash script can help you.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
for i in `ls`
do
    if [ -d $i ];then
        rm -rf $i
    fi
done
```